# get specific array data from json with php / mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla2.5

i have a field in my database that is encoded in json. i think. (part of a joomla/zoo installation).
i need to retrieve a specific value from it (primary_category).

i have enclosed the following code in my template that displays the data

```
   $database = &JFactory::getDBO();
$sql = "SELECT params FROM #__zoo_item";
    $database->setQuery( $sql );
$row=$database->loadResult();
$row = json_decode($row, TRUE);
print_r($row);
```

that returns the below...

```
Array ( [metadata.title] => [metadata.description] => [metadata.keywords] => [metadata.robots] => [metadata.author] => [config.enable_comments] => 1 [config.primary_category] => 601 )
```

what i need to do is just grab the 601 value. i have tried $row[config.primary_category] and $row[6] but neither work.

i am not sure (since i really dont know what i am doing) if i did the json decode wrong or if its a problem with the way i am accessing the array.

Comment: use this code $row['config.primary_category']

Comment: oh my god. the quotes get me every time! is that because it was a string?

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` to see in more detail what you're dealing with...

Comment: @liz The quotes are because the key is a string not an integer. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: And set your error_reporting setting to -a and display_Errors=On in php.ini or using ini_set ...

Comment: @TariqAziz you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

use this code $row['config.primary_category']